# Why am I getting a syntax error ('{' unmatched) in this SL4A script?

Tags: shell, sl4a

I have written a shell script to reconnect my router.

When I run it on my PC with Cygwin, it works fine, but now I want to run it on my smartphone in a SL4A shell, and I get an error:

> `reconnect.sh[4]` syntax error: `'{'` unmatched

This is the script I'm using:

```
#! /system/bin/sh
echo "script start"
sleep 3
strindex() { 
  x="${1%%$2*}"
  [[ $x = $1 ]] && echo -1 || echo ${#x}
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The line `tokenStringEnd=${tokenString##*= }` seems to have the second closing brace commented out in the SO syntax. Is it possible that Cygwin’s seeing it, but SL4A doesn’t? (I don’t really know either of those shells, sorry.)

Comment: means the reconnect.sh[4] that the error is on line 4 ?

Comment: Oops, I missed that. Guess not then. :(

Comment: That's apparently a line breaks problem. Try this: `tr -d '\r' reconnect.sh > reconnect_unix.sh` and then execute `reconnect_unix.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error:

```
#!/bin/sh
strindex() { x="${1%%$2*}" [[ $x = $1 ]] && echo -1 || echo ${#x} }
```

in one line.

Cygwin seems to resolve linebreaks but SL4A doesn't!

Comment: I assume you mean that the one-liner above can't work, because it's missing a `;` before `}`. What do you mean by "resolving linebreaks"?